# How to forward local DNS queries to a VM when macOS is in offline mode?

Tags: macos, dns, port-forwarding

For a project I need to intercept/redirect DNS queries to a VM, which in turn runs `dnsmasq`. This VM is hosted by xhyve and when connected to the network, the setup works well; I have an file in `/etc/resolver.conf/test.io` which has:

```
nameserver 192.168.64.20
search_order 1
```

Doing `dig node.test.io @192.168.64.20` or `dig node.test.io` give the expected results.

But when going offline, there is a problem. It seems that when macOS is not connected to a network, it only allows `/etc/resolver.conf/*` entries to work when they use `127.0.0.1`.

I tried setting up a port-forwarding, like:

```
$ echo "                           
rdr pass inet proto udp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 53 -> 192.168.64.20 port 53
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

and changing `/etc/resolver.conf/test.io` to:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search_order 1
```

However, the domain `test.io` can not be found when I try to do a `nslookup` or `dig node.test.io @localhost`. The VM is still reachable as `dig node.test.io @192.168.64.20` still gets resolved.

`scutil --dns` gives the following:

```
resolver #9
  domain   : test.io
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)
  order    : 1
```

Note: `nslookup` does not seem to handle resolver well, so I have also tried to use curl/wget and the browser to see if queries got resolved correctly. Also, no difference with `dns-sd`. All failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In disconnected mode there is no DNS query going at all... We solved this by adding a TUN/TAP device to the macOS node and 'pretend' with this that it is connected.